# Schema validation failed with the following errors: Data path "" must NOT have additional properties(inlineStyleLanguage)

Tags: angular, google-analytics

After installing ngx-google-analitics on my angular 12 webapp, my app doesn't compile anymore dropping the following error:

Schema validation failed with the following errors:
Data path "" must NOT have additional properties(inlineStyleLanguage).

Tried updating local npm and ng and global too plus CLI and nothing. Could you friends help me, please!? :-)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem that I could resolve by using this command :

> ng update @angular-devkit/build-angular

Hope that's help you :)

Comment: Hi! I'll give a try and post here if I solve the issue. Thnx! :-)